# How can I remove a line running across the top of the first page of the pages for references?

Tags: header-footer

I used

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\chapter}% <cmd>
  {plain}% <search>
  {main}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\fancypagestyle{main}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}% Page in Right header
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
```

to put the page number for the first page of the list of references at the top right corner, but it also gave a line running across the top of the page. How do I delete this line? Also, I am using `biblio.sty` for references.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}` says you want a horizontal line on the top of the page, with width 0.4pt. You can change the latter to 0pt to remove the line.

Comment: @Yori: Thank you for the suggestion. It worked.

Comment: @Yori Please make your comment an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}` states that you want a horizontal line on the top of the page, with width 0.4pt. You can change the latter to 0pt to remove the line entirely.